# Curriculum Vitae vs Resume

Tags: job-search, resume, recruitment, recruiting, south-africa

Which one is more recognized\preferred by recruiters between a CV and a resume? I am currently trying to find employment and I don't know which one is better.

Comment: The answer depends on where you are looking, and what job

Comment: Is there a way for me to find out which one is used in my locale? I'm from South Africa. @joeStrazzere

Comment: But how does one find out if a resume is most prefered in a particular field or profession than others @mhoran_psprep

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most places/locales these are more or less the same.

In academia C.V. often means it includes a complete list of your publications, classes taught, certification, grants etc. In this domain the resume would be a summary of the C.V..

You should always apply with what you feel gives you the best chances of being hired. That typically means

1. Reasonably short, not more than two pages
2. Easy to read and quickly scan
3. Focus on your main achievements and core skills, specifically the ones that are key to the job you are applying to
4. Focus more on the recent past and keep the old stuff complete but as short as possible.
5. Is compliant with expectations, rules and norms in your local area and/or domain, which can vary a lot from place to place. Global applications are a little more tricky, so some research is advised.
6. Provides all info the job requirements specifically asks for, unless this can be provided in the cover letter.

Comment: 7. Absolutely perfect for spelling, punctuation and grammar.

Comment: Throwing @Matt 's comment in the bin since it's missing an Oxford comma... ;)

Comment: Spelling is a little less important these days since most people who read it can't spell either (without spell check tools) ;-)